# Deploying/Pushing subdirectory from one git repository to another one

Tags: git, web-deployment, dvcs, branching-and-merging, git-subtree

I own two git repositories:  **A** and **B**, both mainly used on their own master branch.

**A** contains these folders:

- **folder1**
- **folder2**

**B** contains this folder:

- **folder3**

In order to deploy **A** containing **folder3**, I want to push `folder3` from **B**, to **A**.
I want this kind of relationship as only unidirectional, meaning **A** updates **B** but no `pull` from **B** to **A**.

I would end up with A containing these files:

- **folder1**
- **folder2**
- **folder3** (pushed)

Of course, concerning the first deployment, **A** was unaware of the existence of **folder3**.

Therefore, I found the command [git subtree](http://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/) on the web that seems to achieve this tasks nicely.

So the whole procedure I did to try achieving this task on the **B** repository's directory is:

```
git remote add A https://githubAdressOfA
git subtree prefix --folder3 --squash A master
```

However, I came across this kind of error:

```
Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
```

According to me, `pull` on **B** repo should not be needed with the concept of "subtree" in case of my unidirectional scenario explained above.

How to deal efficiently with this case? Perhaps I misused `subtree` command...

Comment: Currently, I am just configuring my script (actually a grunt task in B) in order to declare the output directory as being A repository's folder; then committing A. Of course, this works well when I own the two repositories on local. Could be great if this could make with a git task.